# How to configure maven for alternate deployment repos?

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I've been reading the [docs for the deploy plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), and am confused about the altDeployment repository parameters.

There are these three params:

- altDeploymentRepository
- altReleaseDeploymentRepository
- altSnapshotDeploymentRepository

Whereas the altRelease and altSnapshot seem to be fairly straightfoward, I'm not sure what the altDeploymentRepository setting is for.  Is that supposed to be a superset of the Snapshot and Release?

Can someone clarify the difference between the three settings and when to use which?

Answer (score 1):

## `altDeploymentRepository`

No idea

## `altReleaseDeploymentRepository`

Let's say you are going to build the artifact which does not have any `SNAPSHOT` attached to your pom file. Ex: `43.0.1` (this is release version) `43.0.1-SNAPSHOT` (this is `SNAPSHOT` version), release version will always be unique...also it means you have properly tested all the code.
So when you define `releaseRepo`, your artifact will load into the release repository

## `altSnapshotDeploymentRepository`

`SNAPSHOT` artifact is useful for initial testing: once you build the code, respective artifact will load into the snapshot repository

Comment: Thanks - but that's the biggest question.  Why bother with `altDeploymentRepository` with the 2 other options available...  Like I said, the two others are relatively self-explanatory.  But I can't figure out the significance of the first one with the two subsequent ones.

Comment: It looks like `altDeploymentRepository` is supposed to be a catch-all, for when you want to define both snapshots and releases to deploy to the same server. Total BS guess, though.